# Azure Application Insights OnPrem reports "server requests" for only one of four IIS sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis

We have one Internet Information Server (IIS) 7.5.7600.16385 (OS 2008 R2) with four sites running PHP,Javascript and ASP. Application Insights Status monitor is installed. All sites are reporting server telemetry data to azure. All sites have identical ApplicationInsights.config and web.configs. Only one site is reporting server requests which we can see under the performance blade on Azure ARM.

My question is why are the other three sites not reporting Performance data such as Server Requests?

Notes on what I have tried so far:

1. Restarted IIS and the server.
2. Checked permissions on the application pool performance monitor groups.
3. Re-created the application insights objects.
4. Verified each application pool is using .Net Framework v4.0.30319

I added a screenshot of my Application Insights Status Monitor Below
The four sites I want are enabled.

[Application Insights Status Monitor Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZszYc.png)

I am seeing these errors:

03/02/2017 10:12:49.786 Application Trace. Level: Error; Id: 8; Message: Error collecting 1 of the configured performance 
counters. Please check the configuration. /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131329519085091332;

Comment: Can you open Status Monitor and double check that all web sites are selected there for monitoring?

Comment: Hello ZakiMa, I posted a screenshot of my Status Monitor, I verified that the four websites that needed to be monitored are selected.